# how to insert bulk data using sequelize and mysql in node js without using looping for insert query

Tags: mysql, insert, sequelize.js, bulk

how to insert a array or json into the table?
array or json contain all the field and there values.

```
{
 "userId":24,
 "addressList":[{ "city":"delhi",
                  "state":"delhi"
                },
                { "city":"gurugram",
                 "state":"hariyana"
                },
                { "city":"dehradun",
                  "state":"uttrakhand"
                }]
}
```

table detail:
userId  city    state
24  delhi   delhi
24  Gurugram    Hariyana
24  Dehradun    uttrakhand

Answer (score 0):

Use `bulkCreate()` function in sequelize.

```
 User.bulkCreate([
   { username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'foo', isAdmin: true },
  { username: 'bar', isAdmin: false }
]).then(() => { // Notice: There are no arguments here, as of right now you'll have to...
  return User.findAll();
}).then(users => {
  console.log(users) // ... in order to get the array of user objects
})
```

This is one sample example. [Refer to this for bulk create docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html#working-in-bulk-creating-updating-and-destroying-multiple-rows-at-once-)